# How to retrieve employee names from a table in oracle DB which are having exactly one 'a/A' in their name?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having an Employee table in my Oracle DB. Now, I want to get all the details of employees who're having exactly one 'a/A' in their name(Assume that the employee names are present in the column called 'ename'.)

Answer (score 1):

you can use like operator

```
select * from employees where name like '%a/A%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE name LIKE '%a%' AND name NOT LIKE '%a%a%';
```

This would match all employees having one and only one `A/a` in their name.  Note that `LIKE` in Oracle is by default case insensitive, so `%a%` matches both cases of the letter.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression option:

```
SQL> with test (name) as
  2    (select 'Littlefoot'  from dual union all
  3     select 'Stacko'      from dual union all
  4     select 'Alguersuari' from dual union all
  5     select 'Argo'        from dual
  6    )
  7  select name
  8  from test
  9  where regexp_count(name, 'a', 1, 'i') = 1;

NAME
-----------
Stacko
Argo

SQL>
```